# accessing parameters of multipart json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a post request to a Rails JSON API server that looks like that:

```
POST /api/posts.json HTTP/1.1
Accepts: application/json
X-API-KEY: 7d867d16a5e25337b6d7857965f812bee73b76ac
Content-Length: 288
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=syoYQUQsGwI2XqShQimFdv2QSe-_GYbjVx40T1kS
Host: 10.0.2.2:3000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

--syoYQUQsGwI2XqShQimFdv2QSe-_GYbjVx40T1kS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="DATA"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{"tags":["dffdff"],"location_id":3,"post":{"content":"test #dffdff"}}
--syoYQUQsGwI2XqShQimFdv2QSe-_GYbjVx40T1kS--
```

how do I access the JSON params ?

if I write params[:DATA] to log I see the attributes, but everything nested is empty (such as params[:DATA][:post] or params[:DATA][:tags]

UPDATE:

when i'm trying to do

```
Rails.logger.debug(params[:DATA])
```

I get

```
{"tags":["dffdff"],"location_id":3,"post":{"content":"test #dffdff"}}
```

but when I try

```
Rails.logger.debug(params[:DATA][:post])
```

I get

```
TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):
  app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb:19:in `[]'
  app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

Comment: Is the `params[:DATA]` a string, array or other type?

Comment: it's the form name of the multipart part, you can see the complete request in the question

Comment: Does params[:DATA]['tags'] work ? I'm not sure if rails runs parsed json though the `with_indifferent_access` stuff

Comment: no it doesn't work..
how do I access those JSON params ?

Comment: I updated the question with the log output

Comment: I found out that I can access those params with JSON(params[:POSTDATA])["post"], is that the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that `params[:DATA]` is a string, but you are treating it like a hash.

You'll need to parse the JSON-string into a Ruby hash, like so:

```
     data = JSON.parse(params[:DATA])
     puts data['post']
```

If you want to use symbols in the hash, i.e. `[:post]`, then you can do:

```
     data = data.with_indifferent_access
     puts data[:post]
```

NB. If you want to test this out in a ruby console, rather than using `params[:DATA]`, you can init data on the first line with:

```
     data = JSON.parse('{"tags":["dffdff"],"location_id":3,"post":{"content":"test #dffdff"}} ')
```

Comment: nb. this was tested with rails 3.2.3, ruby 1.9.3p125